# How to handle a dict API response? Not true JSON with Json.dumps

Tags: python, json, api, dictionary

After I take the API response, and turn it to json. How do I then recall the json.

In the future, it will store in a database, but for now CSV is okay. I've tried CSV writer, but no success.

```
site = 'http://www.micxxxxnk.com'

output = analyze(site, analyze_headings=True, analyze_extra_tags=True)
fields = ['pages']
data = output["pages"]

with open("output.json", "w", encoding = 'utf-8') as file:


json.dump(output, file, indent=4)
```

\

Sample Output:

```
{
"pages": [
    {
        "url": "http://www.mixxxxink.com",
        "title": "mixxxxnk: ai-driven technology for solving real life problems",
        "description": "create amazing experiences, verify users at scale and automate your document-based workflow with ai tech built for a remote world.",
        "word_count": 653,
        "keywords": [
            [
                17,
                "identity"
            ],
            [
                13,
```

Comment: What is the `analyze` function?  The `output` is clearly a `dict` and you serialized it as `json` via `json.dump`, so what is the problem here?

Comment: "however, it is not a true json format as the API response returns a dictionary" I can't understand the problem. The sample output that you show looks like (the beginning of) perfectly valid JSON to me. "A dictionary" is what you get by parsing a JSON document using the standard library `json` module, or via the `.json()` method of Response objects in the third party `requests` library, or by any other reasonable method. Presumably, `analyze` does this internally. An "API response" can **only ever** be raw data, because it is being received by a network connection.

Comment: "I've been struggling with how to parse this properly in order to send it to a database to recall later (most likely DynamoDB)." I can't understand what kind of "parsing" you think is necessary, or why. I also can't understand what "sending" the data to a database is suppose to entail. There is no way we can advise as to "the best way forward", first off because that is subjective, and second because there isn't an identifiable problem here yet. (I can assure you that `json.dump` and `json.dumps` only output valid JSON, or else raise an exception.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**json.dump()** is serializing the python dict object as a valid json formatted stream to your json file, so you got no problem with that

Comment: I am starting to realize I am asking the wrong question. I appreciate your time. I then need to recall this to be able to store in a table or database.